# Javascript filter method, Remove all Items with matching values in array

Tags: javascript, filter

I'm trying to remove all items if they match with array values but it's removing only one item. How can i remove all items with filter method or what is the best way to achieve this.

```
let data = [
    {
        id: '1',
        title: 'ABC'
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        title: 'DEF'
    },
    {
        id: '3',
        title: 'GHI'
    },
    {
        id: '4',
        title: 'JKL'
    },
    {
        id: '5',
        title: 'MNO'
    }
]


data = data.filter(post => {

    let remove = ['2', '4', '5']

    for(let i = 0; i < remove.length; i++) {
        return post.id !== remove[i]
    }

})

console.log(data)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suggest using [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) rather then a nested for loop.

You should also move the `remove` var outside of the loop, so it's not reinitialised every time.

The callback to the `filter` method is a `predicate`. If the condition evaluates to `true`, the current value in the iteration will be returned. In your case, you want to return if the current value is **not** in the remove array.

```js
let data = [
  {
      id: '1',
      title: 'ABC'
  },
  {
      id: '2',
      title: 'DEF'
  },
  {
      id: '3',
      title: 'GHI'
  },
  {
      id: '4',
      title: 'JKL'
  },
  {
      id: '5',
      title: 'MNO'
  }
]

const remove = ['2', '4', '5']

data = data.filter(post => {
  return !remove.includes(post.id)
})

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 3):

you should return false if you want to remove item from array

```js
let data = [
    {
        id: '1',
        title: 'ABC'
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        title: 'DEF'
    },
    {
        id: '3',
        title: 'GHI'
    },
    {
        id: '4',
        title: 'JKL'
    },
    {
        id: '5',
        title: 'MNO'
    }
]
let remove = ['2', '4', '5']

data = data.filter(post => {
return !remove.includes(post.id);
})

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 3):

All the notice are in the snippet's comment

```js
let data = [ { id: '1', title: 'ABC' }, { id: '2', title: 'DEF' }, { id: '3', title: 'GHI' }, { id: '4', title: 'JKL' }, { id: '5', title: 'MNO' } ]

const remove = ['2', '4', '5']

// `indexOf` is from ES5
data = data.filter(post => remove.indexOf(post.id) === -1)
console.log(data)

// `includes` is from ES7
data = data.filter(post => !remove.includes(post.id))
console.log(data)

// this will recreate the array ['2', '4', '5'] 5 times
data = data.filter(post => !['2', '4', '5'].includes(post.id))
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use `for` loop inside of `filter`.

Instead it is possible to use `some` method inside of `filter`. The `some` method checks whether **at least one element** satisfies condition inside of provided function. So unnecessary iteration will be avoided:

```
data.filter(f => !remove.some(s => s == f.id))
```

An example:

```js
let data = [
    {
        id: '1',
        title: 'ABC'
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        title: 'DEF'
    },
    {
        id: '3',
        title: 'GHI'
    },
    {
        id: '4',
        title: 'JKL'
    },
    {
        id: '5',
        title: 'MNO'
    }
]

let remove = ['2', '4', '5']

console.log(data.filter(f => !remove.some(s => s == f.id)));
```